# Take the value from array in php and explode

Tags: php

I have this the values of in my array as

```
$itsthere = (item1-0-100, item2-0-50, item3-0-70, item4-0-50, item5-0-100);
```

If the user enter the value `item3` he has to get `70` which is present in array. I tried alot using explode but its not showing proper value. Can any one help me.

Comment: "I tried alot" -- what precisely have you tried?

Comment: Don't just tell us that you tried using explode, show how you tried to do it.

Comment: And are these strings? `array("item1-0-100", "item2-0-50", ...)` or is one of the parts a key?

Comment: What does your code look like at the moment? If you post what you are using, we can probably look at it and see what the problem is. As it stands, someone has to write a completely new bit of code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
    $item = 'item3';
    $itsthere = array('item1-0-100', 'item2-0-50', 'item3-0-70', 'item4-0-50', 'item5-0-100');

    foreach($itsthere as $there)
    {
        $exp = explode('-',$there);
        if($exp[0] == 'item3') {
            echo $val = $exp[2];
        };
    }
```

Comment: There are two ways to improve performace - `break` after found result and `strpos` before unnecessary `explode` - as in my answer.

Comment: break barely improves performance, it's still O-n in algorithm speak.  If you want to improve performance, iterate (O-n) the array *once* and create a lookup table, instead of O-n performance every single time.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty ok next time i will doing like this.

Comment: whats wrong in this george, i use break; after echo $val = $exp[2];

Comment: is there any problem in this code... i said its easy means its easy to understand... please confirm me is there any probelm in this code?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty why you remove answer ?

Comment: i cant see any problem in this code... its fine.. if any one have suggestion ur welcome

Comment: @GeorgeJempty you suggested solution to everyone but why you removed your answer if other are wrong . and why downvote me?

Comment: I removed my answer because it was like "casting pearls before swine".  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearls_before_swine: "you should not put what is valuable in front of those who will reject the notion that it has value and furthermore that they will seek to diminish or destroy what you offer."  It got downvoted in retaliation for me down voting other peoples crappy answers.  I'm sorry you guys are half-trained PHP morons, if you'd like to begin to change that, learn what a lookup table is

Answer (score 5):

Try with:

```
$itsthere = array(
  'item1-0-100',
  'item2-0-50',
  'item3-0-70',
  'item4-0-50',
  'item5-0-100'
);

$search = 'item3';
$output = '';

foreach ( $itsthere as $value ) {
  if ( strpos($search . '-', $value) === 0 ) {
    $output = explode('-', $value)[2];
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo `@strpos($seach ...`

Comment: What if the user needs to do this over and over again?  There's a much better way

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Suggest something then. :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you say item3 are you refering to the third position or the item3 as array key? I think you can create a assoc array and make item names as key

```
$isthere = array('item1' => '0-100', 'item2' => '0-50' ,'item3' => '0-70', ....,);
echo $isthere['item3']; // This would give you the value.
```

If you only want to know if this key is in the array use array_key_exists.